# Error: How to Select statement according to LogIn page in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, session

I have 2 pages: LogIn page, UpdateInformation page. If the user logIn , he will go to updateInforamtion page to update his information.
My prblem is on (myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();) : How Can I select row depend on LogIn page.
Error is: Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

in Update page I wrote this code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string StudentId = Session["StudentId"].ToString();
            if (Session["FirstName"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
  string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AHSConnection"].ToString();    
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                MySqlDataReader myReader = null;    
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from student where S_Id=" + StudentId + "';", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    lblStudentId.Text = Session["StudentId"].ToString();
                    txtFirstName.Text = myReader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    txtLastName.Text = myReader["LastName"].ToString();    
                    if (RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue(myReader["level"].ToString()) != null)
                    {
                        RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = myReader["level"].ToString();
                    }
                    if (RadioButtonList2.Items.FindByValue(myReader["LO_interested"].ToString()) != null)
                    {
                        RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue = myReader["LO_interested"].ToString();
                    }
                }   
                    conn.Close();
            }
```

In Log In page i wrote this code:

```
 if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Session["FirstName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
                    Session["LastName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();
                    Session["StudentId"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["S_Id"].ToString();
                    Session["level"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["level"].ToString();
                    Session["LO_interested"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LO_interested"].ToString();
```

Comment: Well, I'll take a wild guess and say that 'You have an error in your SQL syntax' ;-)  Is it possible your 'S_id = ' should have quotes?  Is this a string, integer?? Take the exact command text your code produces and try running it directly against the DB

Comment: You do not have a single quote before student ID, but you do have one after, which is probably why you have a syntax error.  If Student ID is a string, add the leading quote, otherwise remove trailing quote.

Comment: I think Bert is correct.  You'll need two quotes or zero depending on the column type.